# artisteer wp-theme metadata (date, category) lost

Tags: php, wordpress

I am going nuts over wordpress and artisteer. I am trying something that used to be pretty straightforward - turning on and off the display of date and post category for my posts on my blog page.

I find this in content.php

```
global $post;
theme_post_wrapper(
    array(
        'id' => theme_get_post_id(), 
        'class' => theme_get_post_class(),
        'title' => theme_get_meta_option($post->ID, 'theme_show_page_title') ? get_the_title() : '', 
        'heading' => theme_get_option('theme_single_article_title_tag'), 
        'before' => theme_get_metadata_icons('date', 'header'),
        'content' => theme_get_content()
    )
);
```

And the instruction says that all you got to do is insert or remove 'date' in the 'before' line. I've done it back and forth with my content files and nothing changes on the output.

I can't find the actual code that prints it all, wordpress used to be so simple before everything was dug down 10 levels deep and you now have to look through millions of different functions to find the simplest things...

As you can probably tell, I usually don't work with WP =) But this is on my table now and I haven't stayed up to date with WP for a couple of years...

Any input as to where I can find the variables is appreciated...

I had expected to at some point find

'posted at '.echo($date).' in category '.echo($category)

or something at least remotely similar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha!  Figured it out!  The before function needed to go AFTER the `h2` tag:

```
<div class="post-inner article">
    <?php echo $thumbnail;
      if (!art_is_empty_html($title)){
          echo '<h2 class="postheader">'.$title.'</h2>';
      }
      echo $before;
    ?>
<div class="postcontent">
<!-- article-content -->
```

Leaving this here in case someone else comes looking for it!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into this problem of not having any post metadata (published date, category etc.) in my Artisteer theme. I had disabled them in the artisteer design program, because i didn't want my entire page to look like a blog but rather a professional page.

However, later I realized I did want those data of published date, post category etc. for my news section (which was indeed just a blog page).

How do I get it back?

Turns out that was a bit harder than you'd think... in earlier versions of WP and artisteer, you could just find the file handling the output, i.e. index, page etc. but now it's all wrapped up in functions calling each other =)

It goes like this:
Each page in WP has a template file (can be specified when creating the page), read more about page templates in the WP Codex.
Your blog page runs off of the home.php or archive.php (depending on whether or not you are viewing an archive of posts or just the regular "home" item, I call mine "news" since the blog is just a small news section of my site).

The loop that prints out the posts look like this:

```
/* Start the Loop */ 
while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    get_template_part('content', '');
}
```

So all that is controlled in this page template file regarding post output is which content filter template to use. In your artisteer 3.1 theme you would have a number of content.php files, the function above will call the content.php but you can have a content-page.php for your pages etc. Let's take a look at my content.php then...

```
global $post;
theme_post_wrapper(
    array(
            'id' => theme_get_post_id(), 
            'class' => theme_get_post_class(),
            'thumbnail' => theme_get_post_thumbnail(),
            'title' => theme_get_meta_option($post->ID, 'theme_show_page_title') ? get_the_title() : '', 
            'heading' => theme_get_option('theme_'.(is_single()?'single':'posts').'_article_title_tag'),
            'before' => theme_get_metadata_icons('date,category', 'header' ),

            'content' => theme_get_excerpt(), 
            'after' => theme_get_metadata_icons( '', 'footer' )
    )
);
```

So all that this file really does is determining which parts of data to include with this template. When I had drilled down here, I started getting annoyed... where is the actual code that prints my html elements? Where can I start 'hacking' my theme? As you may see, the line for 'before' above contains items 'data, category' and an additional value for styling, 'header'. So let's look at that function in our themes functions.php...

```
function theme_get_metadata_icons($icons = '', $class=''){
        global $post;
        if (!is_string($icons) || theme_strlen($icons) == 0) return;
        $icons = explode(",", str_replace(' ', '', $icons));
        if (!is_array($icons) || count($icons) == 0) return;
        $result = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($icons); $i++){
            $icon = $icons[$i];
            switch($icon){
                case 'date':
                    $result[] = '<span class="art-postdateicon">' . sprintf( __('<span class="%1$s">Published</span> %2$s', THEME_NS),
                                    'date',
                                    sprintf( '<span class="entry-date" title="%1$s">%2$s</span>',
                                        esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
                                        get_the_date()
                                    )
                                ) . '</span>';
                break;
                case 'category':
                    $categories = get_the_category_list(', ');
                    if(theme_strlen($categories) == 0) break;
                    $result[] = '<span class="art-postcategoryicon">' . sprintf(__('<span class="%1$s">Posted in</span> %2$s', THEME_NS), 'categories', get_the_category_list(', ')) . '</span>';
                break;
//other options such as author etc. are included here by default, I took them out for the sake of this example...
            }
        }
        $result = implode(theme_get_option('theme_metadata_separator'), $result);
        if (theme_is_empty_html($result)) return;
        return "<div class=\"art-post{$class}icons art-metadata-icons\">{$result}</div>";
    }
```

So that function only extracts some data, and wraps it in some theme styling, but still I haven't found where I can comment out the actual html elements containing the information on "posted by" etc.
Remember I had lost the date stamp, so I thought it was commented out somewhere.

The last place to look is now the function theme_post_wrapper(), if you step back one step, you'll see that theme_post_wrapper() is the function which is in turn calling the above function which extracted the data and wrapped it in some styling elements. You'd think that this function would be somewhere in functions.php right? But no... a directory search for function theme_post_wrapper( showed that it is in the theme file library/wrappers.php. And it looks like this:

```
function theme_post_wrapper($args = '') {
    $args = wp_parse_args($args, 
        array(
            'id' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'title' => '',
            'heading' => 'h2',
            'thumbnail' => '',
            'before' => '',
            'content' => '',
            'after' => ''
        )
    );

    /*
        var_dump($args);
        die;
    */

    extract($args);
    if (theme_is_empty_html($title) && theme_is_empty_html($content)) return;
    if ($id) {
        $id = ' id="' . $id . '"';
    }
    if ($class) {
        $class = ' ' . $class; 
    }
    ?>
<div class="art-box art-post<?php echo $class; ?>"<?php echo $id; ?>>
        <div class="art-box-body art-post-body">
                <div class="art-post-inner art-article">
                <?php
                    if (!theme_is_empty_html($title)){
                        echo '<'.$heading.' class="art-postheader">'$before.': '.$title.' <span class="published_date">('.$after.')</span></'.$heading.'>';
                    //original:   echo '<'.$heading.' class="art-postheader">'.$title.'</'.$heading.'>';
                    }
                     echo $thumbnail;
                    ?>
                    <div class="art-postcontent">
                        <!-- article-content -->
                        <?php echo $content; ?>
                        <!-- /article-content -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="cleared"></div>
                    <?php
                ?>
                </div>
            <div class="cleared"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is where my metadata elements are finally printed, now I feel at home and all is right with the world again. Once more I appreciate Artisteer, though it was a bit of a mess and quite time consuming to get down to the nuts and bolts on this one.

Note on the solution to my problem: Artisteer works like this: when you choose not to inclute the date or author metadata in your theme, artisteer doesn't just turn off an option or comment out the code for the printing of these elements, it actually doesn't generate that code at all. So I had to manually put it back in there. Fair enough - I guess artisteer themes weren't made to be hacked and tweaked in this manner, still I like them a whole lot better than tha logics of those twentyten and twentyeleven themes =p